# How can I add a text on an image in iphone?

Tags: ios, image-processing

I need to put a text over an image in iPhone. It's like the Eurosport iPhone app.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mzstatic.com](http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/092/Purple/v4/fa/d6/9e/fad69e44-29e2-a123-2a74-ad58ba5de36e/mza_1083026897138509692.320x480-75.jpg))</sub>

In the same way I need to put a text in my app. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: simple, just put an `UILabel` on the `UIImageView` and you've done it!

Answer (score 9):

I found two ways

**1:**

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 25, 200, 200);
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Choice set.png"];

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
    myLabel.text = @"Hello There";
    myLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [imageView addSubview:myLabel];

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    [imageView release];
    [myLabel release];
```

**2:**

**Add text to UIImage**

```
-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1{

   int w = img.size.width;
   int h = img.size.height;
   CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
   CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);

   char* text= (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial",20, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
   CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
   CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context,10,10,text, strlen(text));
   CGImageRef imgCombined = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

   CGContextRelease(context);
   CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

   UIImage *retImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgCombined];
   CGImageRelease(imgCombined);

   return retImage;
}
```

then call

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];

imageView.image = [self addText:image text:@"Hello there"];
```

Comment: it is probably too complicated for this simple issue.

Comment: @Ramshad +1 on the second method. Very useful. Everything got released properly, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple make label with clear background.

```
yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```