# Adding text on image in iphone

Tags: iphone

How to add the text on image,and make it dynamic since the user will enter the text in the textfield and while preview of the image it should be as image,where text should appear where the user placed the textfield.

Comment: see SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739007/how-can-i-add-a-text-on-an-image-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

you will simply have to put a label with background clear and add it to the view where image is getting displayed. To make it dynamic, you will have to put up textfield (where user enters text) delegate methods. Once there is any change in the textfield of the user, update the label text.